# Joining two aggregated queries

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables that look like this

**users**:

```
id | created_at
```

**payments**:

```
id | created_at
```

I need a table that is grouped by year and month and contains both number of users and payments

**stats**:

```
month | year | users | payments
```

Where `users` column contains number of registered users and `payments` - number of payments. I can get two tables separately, but how can I join them?

```
select 
    month(created_at) as month, 
    year(created_at) as year, 
    count(*) users
from 
    users 
group by 
    month, year 
having 
    users > 0 
order by 
    year desc, month desc;

select 
    month(created_at) as month, 
    year(created_at) as year, 
    count(*) payments
from 
    payments 
group by 
    month, year 
having 
    payments > 0 
order by 
    year desc, month desc;
```

Comment: Tag RDBMS yuo're using.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you're looking for :

```
select a.*, b.payments from (
    select month(created_at) as month, year(created_at) as year, count(*) users
    from users group by month, year having users > 0 order by year desc, month desc
) a left join (
    select month(created_at) as month, year(created_at) as year, count(*) payments
    from payments group by month, year having payments > 0 order by year desc, month desc
) b on a.month = b.month and b.year = b.year
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I join two tables that have different set of months.

Comment: Obviously.. How do you want to join datasets when you have nathing to join on? Or you want to display just the results side-by-side? Maybe you want to do a `cross join`?

Comment: I've got the result with left join.

Comment: @osukono I edited answer, so it's what you wanted, so future readers may benefit :)

Answer (score 0):

The comparison to `users > 0` and `payments > 0` are useless.  In addition, `order by` in subqueries is meaningless.

You can do this with a `full join`:

```
select month, year, coalesce(users, 0) as users, coalesce(payments, 0) as payments
from (select month(created_at) as month, year(created_at) as year, 
             count(*) as users
      from users
      group by month, year 
     ) u full join
     (select month(created_at) as month, year(created_at) as year,
             count(*) as payments
      from payments
      group by month, year
     ) p
     using (month, year)
order by year desc, month desc;
```

If you know you have users and payments for all months (that you care about), you can use an `inner join` rather than a `full join`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out at coalesce() function, it adds 0 instead of NULL. I use having because the query is going to be more complected and instead of cont(*) there will be sum() aggregation. However it seams like MySQL doesn't support full join and left join gives me the desired result.